# SAS names with prefix not working

Tags: sas

I was trying to get all of the fname variables with the prefix TIME_INTERVAL. However, it seems that the following put statement outputs nothing. I was wondering what is the reason?

```
%LET TIME_INTERVAL='MINUTE15';
data _null_;
set filenames;
by fname;
if fname =: "&TIME_INTERVAL";
put fname;
run;
```

If I put the put statement above the if statement, however, it can output correctly:

```
%LET TIME_INTERVAL='MINUTE15';
data _null_;
set filenames;
by fname;
put fname;
if fname =: "&TIME_INTERVAL";
run;
```

Update:

The content of the dataset filenames:

```
MINUTE15_group0.csv
MINUTE15_group1.csv
MINUTE15_group2.csv
MINUTE15_group3.csv
MINUTE15_group4.csv
MINUTE15_group5.csv
MINUTE15_group6.csv
MINUTE15_group7.csv
MINUTE15_group8.csv
MINUTE5_group0.csv
MINUTE5_group1.csv
MINUTE5_group2.csv
MINUTE5_group3.csv
MINUTE5_group4.csv
MINUTE5_group5.csv
MINUTE5_group6.csv
MINUTE5_group7.csv
MINUTE5_group8.csv
SECOND5_group0.csv
SECOND5_group1.csv
SECOND5_group2.csv
SECOND5_group3.csv
SECOND5_group4.csv
SECOND5_group5.csv
SECOND5_group6.csv
SECOND5_group7.csv
SECOND5_group8.csv
```

Comment: None of your FNAME values have single quotes in them like your macro variable does.

Comment: I think the single quote just means string?

Comment: Everything is a string to the macro processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked SAS to look for filenames that start with `'MINUTE15'`, but I think that you actually wanted to look for filenames that start with `MINUTE15` instead.

Everything is a string to the macro processor so there is no need to add quotes around constant text in macro code. If you add them they become part of the code that is being generated and passed to SAS to run.  So your program generated this IF statement.

```
  if fname =: "'MINUTE15'";
```

You could remove the single quotes.

```
%LET TIME_INTERVAL=MINUTE15;
data _null_;
  set filenames;
  if fname =: "&TIME_INTERVAL";
  put fname;
run;
```

Or remove the double quotes.

```
%LET TIME_INTERVAL='MINUTE15';
data _null_;
  set filenames;
  if fname =: &TIME_INTERVAL;
  put fname;
run;
```

Comment: What's the difference between `%LET TIME_INTERVAL=MINUTE15;` and `%LET TIME_INTERVAL='MINUTE15';`?

Comment: The second will store the single quotes in the macro variable.

Comment: But then why do we need the quote in `if fname =: "&TIME_INTERVAL";`?

Comment: In SAS code you need to use quotes around string literals so that it doesn't look for a variable named MINUTE15.  But macro processing is just used to generate SAS code. You just need to make sure that the generated code is valid SAS syntax and matches what you wanted to generate.